# A Restful Zend Fr API provider that implements OAuth2.0?

Tags: rest, zend-framework, oauth

Has anyone came across a tutorial that explains developing a Restful  Zend Framework API provider that implements OAuth2.0? I have been using  OAuth1.0, but this protocol has some limitations which  OAuth2.0 solves.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you implement OAuth 1.0 under Zend Framework? I don't think Zend_Oauth_Provider is built in the Zend Framework release yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [apigility](http://apigility.org/) that Zend recently announced in ZendCon? It is really easy to create api's and with Zend_Oauth you can create your own service really easy.